# Extract Two Nodes from one XElement and create a new XElement

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, asp.net-mvc

I would like to extract two Nodes from an XElement and create a new XElement with those two Extracted Nodes, my XElement, called addTree looks like:

```
<add>
  <channel_texting_id>7759101659683854745</channel_texting_id> 
  <account_id>1229782938247303441</account_id> 
  <channel_id>3922635293764895812</channel_id> 
  <texting_id>1</texting_id> 
  <is_active>true</is_active> 
  </add>
```

I would like to create a new XElement that is:

```
<channel_texting_id>7759101659683854745</channel_texting_id> <channel_id>3922635293764895812</channel_id>
```

I can get the first node, channel_texting_id with this:

```
var addTreeOnlyDataINeed = n1.FirstNode as XElement;
```

And now I want to add channel_id in XElement addTree to XElement addTreeOnlyDataINeed but I do not know how to select the channel_id node by name in XElement addTree and once I get it how to add, entirely intact and at the same level as channel_texting_id in XElement addTreeOnlyDataINeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
var parsed = XElement.Parse('here your xml as string');

var addTree = new XElement("addTree",
    new XElement("channel_texting_id", parsed.Element("channel_texting_id").Value),
    new XElement("channel_id", parsed.Element("channel_id").Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't store multiple XML elements in single `XEelement` variable. You can use collection of `XElement` instead, for example using `List<T>` :

```
var addTreeOnlyDataINeed = new List<XElement>();
addTreeOnlyDataINeed.Add(n1.FirstNode as XElement);
//this is how you get child element by name
addTreeOnlyDataINeed.Add(n1.Element("channel_id"));
```